# search for string in vi

Tags: search, vi

I want to search for this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `influencers` WHERE (author_name =
```

within a log file using vi, I cant figure out how to properly escape this, I have tried:

```
 SELECT * FROM \`influencers\` WHERE \(author_name =
```

And several similar versions, but no luck

Comment: I think your all kinda right, the only thing I needed to escape was the * though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT \* FROM `influencers` WHERE [(]author_name =
```

EDIT: Seeing Keith's answer, he's right.  My square brackets are unnecessary.  But I'll leave my answer to make a point: whenever I have regex problems, wrapping questionable characters in square brackets is often a quick fix (and doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 1):

In vim, the only character you need to escape is the `*`:

```
/SELECT \* FROM `influencers` WHERE (author_name =
```

If you're using a different vi variant than vim, you'll need to tell us what you're using.